# how to add images using php and specific query

Tags: php, mysql, adobe

My problem is:

i want to add another images , images will be save in database but the id is 0. and it could not display for the user.

database :

## homestay

id (PK)
name
address

## img_homestay

imgid  (PK)
id  (FK)
filename
filetype
filesize
location

the code :

```html
$id=$_GET['id'];
$path = pathinfo($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
 
    for ($i = 0; $i < count ($_FILES['userfile']['name']); $i++)
    {
        $tmp_file = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i];
  $filetype = $_FILES['userfile']['type'][$i];
        $filesize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'][$i];
        $filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$i];
        $destination = $path['dirname'] . '../data/' . $filename;
        if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_file, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $destination))
        {   
  $result = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO img_homestay (id, location, filetype, filename, filesize) VALUES ('$id','$destination', '$filetype', '$filename', '$filesize') ");
        }
    }

   echo "<script>alert(\"Your Homestay Successfully Add an Images!\")</script>";
   header("Location:".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']); 
   mysql_close($link);
```

```html
<table width="322" height="29" border="0" align="right">
          <tr><form action="addimg.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="addimg">
            <th width="120" height="25" scope="row">Add Images</th>
            <td width="121"><input multiple="multiple" type="file" name="userfile[]">*Limit upload to 10 images only </br><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
          </form>
        </table>
```

Comment: check that whether you getting id or not

Comment: Please show HTML code

Comment: display this string(3) "$id" success!.

Comment: @ManishGoyal already show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're dealing with file uploads you are using an HTTP POST not a GET.

Change

`$id=$_GET['id'];`

to

`$id=$_POST['id'];`

NOTE:
In your original query, you use column `id`, which is not in the `img_homestay` schema. Guessing it's a typo in the insert works.

Comment: it shoud be id also. it gets value from id homestay. i have change get to post. but it still same

Comment: Do a print_r($_REQUEST) and make sure id is getting passed to your page.

Comment: Guess you weren't passing the id in your form. Add it as a hidden input and you're good to go.